# How to send Json data to web server in Windows phone 8 application (Not web application)?

Tags: windows-phone-8

My sample code bellow not working.....

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.UploadStringCompleted += client_UploadStringCompleted;
webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(imagesInfo);
webClient.UploadStringAsync(ImpressionUri, "POST", jsonData);
```

Comment: What's not working? Is there an error? Is the URI passed correct? You'll need to add more information as the basics as posted look correct.

Comment: didn't create any error but server is not updated...whats wrong with me i don't find it.

Comment: Please show me the wright way........

Comment: Did the data get sent to the server? You haven't provided enough details to help.

Comment: Thanks @ WiredPrairie for extending your helping hand to me. I've done it, Actually where the problem was i didn't find it clearly. I've only made uri combination of link+jsonData then call webClient.UploadStringAsync(ImpressionUri, "GET");